# Chrome Version mismatch while running Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, selenium, maven, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

I have added a Selenium Project into the Azure pipeline as a maven task. But while running the same pipeline I am getting an error messaged 'Chrome version and chromedriver version is mismatching'.

What should I do to overcome this ?? How to know the chrome version installed inside the windows instance (Each time it takes different windows instance)

Comment: Here you will find list of software installed on [Microsoft Hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Hi Akhil Anand , Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. You could find the software version on host agent from our official doc such as this link https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md Just select corresponding VM image . For example, with windows-2019, 
Google Chrome version: 83.0.4103.61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How does Microsoft choose the software and versions to put on the image?**
>
> More information about the versions of software included on the images
>   can be found at [Guidelines for what's installed](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments#guidelines-for-whats-installed).

In your scenario, since you need a specific chrome version. The best and recommend way is using **self-host agent**.

You can use a self-hosted agent that includes the exact versions of software that you need. For more information, see [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install). In this way, you could even clone an environment on VM as same as your local development, this will help to narrow down build issue which caused by environment.